# Easy way to keep the listeners working while touching the screen

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, multi-touch, ontouchlistener

Here is my scenario: a `LinearLayout` as the main layout of the `Activity`. The Layout contains an `ImageView` which has its own `onClickListener`.

What would be the easiest way  to fire the `ImageView` listener while the user rests his finger on the screen. This is a general scenario where the user is holding the device and touches the screen by mistake(so a onTouch fires) but wants to press the `ImageView`. In this case, since the screen is already touched, when pressing he `ImageView`, nothing happens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can achieve same by using **ACTION_DOWN** & **ACTION_POINTER_DOWN**, where later is for second touch. You need to handle these events in your touchlistner. This listener can be on your root layout.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
}
```

**[See here, some excerpts are](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) :**

```
When multiple pointers touch the screen at the same time, the system generates the following touch events:
ACTION_DOWN—For the first pointer that touches the screen. This starts the gesture. The pointer data for this pointer is always at index 0 in the MotionEvent.
ACTION_POINTER_DOWN—For extra pointers that enter the screen beyond the first. The pointer data for this pointer is at the index returned by getActionIndex().
ACTION_MOVE—A change has happened during a press gesture.
ACTION_POINTER_UP—Sent when a non-primary pointer goes up.
ACTION_UP—Sent when the last pointer leaves the screen.
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for an easier method, but this will have to do.